# Flex SOAP or Flex Plus Server Side SOAP?

Tags: apache-flex, soap

I'm looking to consume SOAP services -- read only -- from a third party web service.

I know Flex has strong SOAP functionality.

I am wondering, however, if there is any benefit to using e.g. Ruby or PHP to consume those 3rd party services and then passing the results to Flex, versus doing it all in Flex.

Other than decoupling the client code from the SOAP logic, I can't really think of one.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This would especially be good if the web service you are consuming returns SOAP 1.2, because Flex doesn't consume 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Only reason you'd do this is if your third party services didn't provide a cross domain policy for your Flex app to communicate with it.

Otherwise you are effectively doubling the roundtrip time of the request for no gain.